# Pytest finds test on the terminal, but not on pycharm

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, pytest

When I run pytest on pycharm by clicking on the 'run' button while it's set to run on the current file. It does not find the test. But when I run pytest on the terminal it finds the test. Pycharm worked for me until I restarted my PC

file name is: 'test_checkout_guest_user.py'

```
import pdb
import pytest
from frameweerk.src.pages.homepage import homepage
from frameweerk.src.pages.Header import Header

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('init_driver')
class TestEndtoendchekoutguestuser:


    @pytest.mark.tcid33
    def test_end_to_end_checkout_guest_user(self):
     home_p= homepage(self.driver)
     header= Header(self.driver)




     home_p.go_to_home_page()

     home_p.click_first_add_to_cart_button()




     header.click_on_cart_header()

     pdb.set_trace()
```

Tried to run pytest on pycharm and it didn't find the test. Ran it on the terminal and the test was found

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm navigate to `Settings` -> `Tools` -> `Python Integrated Tools`.

In section `Testing` check the selected option for `Default test runner` - it should be `pytest`.